# AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command' error while running my code

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to write a discord.py bot that will add a thumbs up to a message which, when clicked, will give the user the role "test". Here is my code I'm using:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

messageIDs = [759721500579463219]

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    global messageIDs

    for messageID in messageIDs:
        if messageID == payload.message_id:
            user = payload.member
            role = "Test"
            await user.add_roles(discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name = role))

@client.command()
async def addMessage(ctx, messageID):
    global messageIDs
    
    emoji = ""
    channel = ctx.message.channel

    try:
        msg = await channel.fetch_message(messageID)
    except:
        await ctx.send("Invalid Message ID!")
        return
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
    messageIDs.append(messageID)

bot.run("Not gonna reveal this")
```

However, when I run the code, I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\james\Desktop\Random Codes\CustomBot.py", line 22, in 
@client.command()
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'

Please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and if possible, rewrite the code with the corrections made, as sometimes I find it hard to work out what people mean by their answers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest you read this https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) instance to use commands, you are using `Client`

See the [ext.commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) docs for more info